# Mapping an Object[] with dozer

Tags: java, dozer

With the help of [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net) I want to map an `Object[]` to a DTO class

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>com.example.myDtoClass</class-a>
    <class-b>java.lang.Object[]</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>prop</a>
            <!-- <b key="1">this</b> -->
        <b>this[1]</b>
        <b-hint>java.lang.String</b-hint>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

but both settings `<b>this[1]</b>` and `<b key="1">this</b>` do not work and the `prop` field is set with the entire `Object[]` field so the result in returned JSON looks like

```
"prop": "[Ljava.lang.Object;@40147864"
```

what am I missing? I am expecting to have the 1 element of the `Object[]` in the `prop` variable

Comment: Why don't you just copy the first element of the array to the type represented by `prop`, then set it into your DTO?

Comment: to avoid boiler plate code. There are 10 elements inside the `Object[]` and I would need to add those 10 lines of code everywhere I need that mapping. And it is needed a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a bad mistake. Yes I get a `Object[]` to map, but the 1 element of that `Object[]` again is of type `Object[]`. I got confused and thought it was the main element. I did though expect a String, but got a array of binary code that has to be joined back to a string.